# php search table by id

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im trying to display all the information from a single row in my database table by the id.

When I click search it shows the entire table and the search really doesnt do anything..

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you :)

[image: table schema]

im using php/mysql

```
<?php 

session_start();
include('connect.php');
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
$q = $_POST['srch_query'];

?>

<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="srch_query" value="<?php echo $q ?>" required>
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
</form>

<?php

$search = $db->prepare("SELECT species, tree_desc, age, city, state, location FROM tree_info");
$search->execute();
if($search->rowcount()==0){ echo "No product found!"; }
else 
{
    echo "Search Result:</br>";?>
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Species</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>City</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Location</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

    <?php foreach($search as $s)
        { ?>

            <tr class="record">
                <td><?php echo $s['species']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $s['tree_desc']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $s['age']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $s['city']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $s['state']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $s['location']; ?></td>
            </tr>

    <?php   }
}
} ?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You should use your `$q` var to filter the query - just sending them does nothing

Comment: You need to use $q from form to create new sql query with wanted search parameters.

Comment: You know there is *documentation* out there that provides these kind of answers right? A simple *"SQL search by column"* would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$q` in your query to filter your resultset. Currently you only send the var to the server, without doing anything with it.

```
$search = $db->prepare("SELECT species, tree_desc, age, city, state, location FROM tree_info WHERE tree_id=:id");
$search->execute([':id' => (int) $q]);
```

Answer (score -3):

Your `$search` variable is a PDOStatement object. You need to fetch result.

Do it this way :

```
<?php 
    $results = $search->fetchAll();
    foreach($results as $s)
    { ?>

        <tr class="record">
            <td><?php echo $s['species']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $s['tree_desc']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $s['age']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $s['city']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $s['state']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $s['location']; ?></td>
        </tr>

<?php   }  ?>
```

And check the doc for more informations on the PDOStatement if needed.
http://php.net/manual/fr/class.pdostatement.php

**EDIT : my bad, I was focusing on the wrong problem.**

You must add your $q to your query if it exists :

```
if ($q) {
    $search = $db->prepare("SELECT species, tree_desc, age, city, state,   location FROM tree_info WHERE id = :id");
    $search->bindParam('id', $q, PDO::PARAM_INT);
} else {
    $search = $db->prepare("SELECT species, tree_desc, age, city, state,     location FROM tree_info");
}
```

Comment: `PDOStatement ` is `Traversable`, so you dont have to explicitly call `fetchAll`. The problem is the missing use of `$q`